# Fail to add Spotify player on my website : "mixed active content error" in console

Tags: iframe, embed, spotify, mixed-content

I want to add a Spotify player directly on a html page, but when I put the embed code from Spotify, it fails to load my page.

#### The embed code is the following:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify:track:5JunxkcjfCYcY7xJ29tLai" 
frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The error code is the following : `Blocage du chargement du contenu mixte actif` (mixed active content) and I really don't know how to solve this problem.

I saw that maybe load the player before I load the page but I don't know how to it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you accessing your page over https? What is the code that you inserted?

Comment: the code is the iframe I put above and Im working local for the moment so dont know for https...